# Form date (yyyy-mm-dd) validation.

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, forms, validation

In my validation file i have a "prepare Data" function that saves to data from the DOM into a JSON and returns it as data.applicants.occupation_since:

```
applicants.occupation_since = mainAppContainer.find(".employmentPeriodStart").val()
```

And then validates it in a "validate" function:

```
        var validateOccupationCompany, validateOccupationSince;
if (data.applicants[0].occupation === 'full_time' || data.applicants[0].occupation === 'hourly' || data.applicants[0].occupation === 'part_time' || data.applicants[0].occupation === 'finite_time') {
   validateOccupationCompany = true;
  validateOccupationSince = true;
}

var dateVal, dateValues, dtDay, dtMonth, dtYear, isleap, validatePattern;
if (validateOccupationSince) {
  dateVal = data.applicants[0].occupation_since;
  validatePattern = /^(\d{4})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})$/;
  dateValues = dateVal.match(validatePattern);
  dtYear = dateValues[1];
  dtMonth = dateValues[3];
  dtDay = dateValues[5];
  if (validatePattern.test(dateVal) !== true) {
    ret.status = false;
    ret.errorMessages.push("SOME ERROR MSG");
    ret.errorClasses.push(".employmentPeriodStart");
  } else if (dtMonth < 1 || dtMonth > 12) {
    ret.status = false;
    ret.errorMessages.push("SOME ERROR MSG.");
ret.errorClasses.push(".employmentPeriodStart");
  } else if (dtDay < 1 || dtDay > 31) {
    ret.status = false;
    ret.errorMessages.push("SOME ERROR MSG.");
    ret.errorClasses.push(".employmentPeriodStart");
  } else if ((dtMonth === 4 || dtMonth === 6 || dtMonth === 9 || dtMonth === 11) && dtDay === 31) {
ret.status = false;
ret.errorMessages.push("SOME ERROR MSG.");
ret.errorClasses.push(".employmentPeriodStart");
  } else if (dtMonth === 2) {
isleap = dtYear % 4 === 0 && (dtYear % 100 !== 0 || dtYear % 400 === 0);
if (dtDay > 29 || (dtDay === 29 && !isleap)) {
  ret.status = false;
  ret.errorMessages.push("SOME ERROR MSG.");
  ret.errorClasses.push(".employmentPeriodStart");
}
}
}
```

I've been stuck trying to make it work for sometime and haven't been able to solve it, and it looks kind of messy atm.

An alternative solution is fine, or if you could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

We've also been struggling with Date, Time and DateTime and its formats.

I would strongly recommend to use [MomentJs](http://momentjs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

For date (yyyy-mm-dd) validation you can use this RegEx.`pattern.test(input)` returns True if date has the same format as you want. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P9TER/488/)

```
var input = '1997-01-01';

var pattern =/^([0-9]{4})\-([0-9]{2})\-([0-9]{2})$/;

alert(pattern.test(input));
```

Then, you can validate like this. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UeQAK/469/)

```
var invalidDate = '2011-30-02';
var comp = invalidDate.split('-');
var m = parseInt(comp[1], 10);
var d = parseInt(comp[2], 10);
var y = parseInt(comp[0], 10);
var date = new Date(y,m-1,d);
if (date.getFullYear() == y && date.getMonth() + 1 == m && date.getDate() == d) {
    alert('Valid date');
} else {
    alert('Invalid date');
}
```

I Hope it helps